# Curl Option to Rename Duplicate File Names During Download

Tags: curl

Is there an option for [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) to automatically change the downloaded file's filename if that filename already exists on disk?

Wget does this automatically by appending a .1, .2, .3, .4 etc... to the end of the file name.

Curl Example:

```
$ ls -al
drwx------. 3 user    user       219 Sep  6 17:12 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 user    user        21 May 12 18:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user    user    147415 Sep  6 16:47 image.jpg

$ curl -O https://website/context/path/image.jpg

$ ls -al
drwx------. 3 user    user       219 Sep  6 17:12 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 user    user        21 May 12 18:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user    user    147415 Sep  6 17:35 image.jpg
```

The above curl command will overwrite the original image.jpg.  Is there a way in curl to cause the new file to be named `image.jpg.1`, or something similar, like in wget?

Wget Example:

```
$ rm image.jpg*
$ wget https://website/context/path/image.jpg

$ ls -al
drwx------. 3 user    user       219 Sep  6 17:12 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 user    user        21 May 12 18:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user    user    147415 Sep  6 17:42 image.jpg

$ wget https://website/context/path/image.jpg
$ wget https://website/context/path/image.jpg
$ wget https://website/context/path/image.jpg

$ ls -al
drwx------. 3 user    user       219 Sep  6 17:12 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 user    user        21 May 12 18:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user    user    147415 Sep  6 17:42 image.jpg
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user    user    147415 Sep  6 17:42 image.jpg.1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user    user    147415 Sep  6 17:42 image.jpg.2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user    user    147415 Sep  6 17:42 image.jpg.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. curl has no such option. If you really need it, you can most often work around it by doing the check yourself in a script or other wrapper program.

This feature is mentioned in curl's TODO as something that would be neat to have, so it might be added at a future point in time...

Comment: Thank you for the information Daniel, it is much appreciated.  I was concerned that was the case, but just wanted to verify.

Answer (score 1):

`--no-clobber`, according to man page, it is "Added in (version) 7.83.0."

Comment: Nice, good find and thanks for the reply.  Only missed this option by 4 years.  :D